# cookiechoices on appspot not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run cookieChoices.js from cookieChoices.org on appspot but I'm getting the following error when I inspect the elements

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://whatsonpontyclun.appspot.com/cookiechoices.js Uncaught ReferenceError: cookieChoices is not defined whatsonpontyclun.appspot.com/:36

I've loaded cookieChoices into the root directory as I understand the instructions but I've also tried loading the file into /static/js which is where I keep my other javascript files.  I get the same errors.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to include code in landing page:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script src="/cookiechoices.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    cookieChoices.showCookieConsentBar('This site uses cookies to improve your reading experience. ',
      'Click here to accept cookies', 'Click here to refuse cookies', 'http://www.islandpublishers.co.uk/cookietest/cookieask.html');
  });
</script>​
```

I am having a problem allowing the user to refuse the cookies.